# Is gmtime() affected by daylight savings?

Tags: utc

My local time zone is EDT.  I have a time stamp: 29 Aug 2003 04:18:52, which I have converted to a time_t value using mktime(), with tm_isdst set to -1.  The time_t value is 1062145132.  When I run gmtime() with this value, I get 29 Aug 2003 09:18:52.  Looking at the struct tm returned from gmtime(), the value of tm_isdst is 1.  Why isn't this time 08:18:52 instead?  Isn't gmtime supposed to be equivalent to UTC, without any daylight savings dependence?

I have used bash as follows:

```
date --date=@1062145132
Fri Aug 29 04:18:52 EDT 2003
TZ=UTC date --date=@1062145132
Fri Aug 29 08:18:52 UTC 2003
```

The above shows the expected 4 hour difference between EDT and UTC.  Why doesn't gmtime() show the same difference?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem.  In between the call gmtime(&tmgmt) and the output of asctime(&tmgmt), I had a call to mktime(&tmgmt).  I had not realized that mktime would possibly change the values in the structure, so that the values I printed out were not those returned from gmtime().